# Advantage of (function() {/*...*/}).call(this);

Tags: javascript

While looking at the code of [uuid.js](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) I have noticed this pattern for the definition of the whole api.

```
(function() {/*...*/}).call(this);
```

What are the advantages of such a pattern in javascript ?

Comment: self executed javascript function.  for [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: @RoyiNamir no, a normal IIFE will use the global context.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Except you can't, because `this` would be the global object. The `.call(this)` overrides this.

Comment: @Alnitak yes you're right. ( I forgot about iife context for `this`). tnx for reminding me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just an *immediately invoked function expression* that has a defined context (`this`).  A normal IIFE will have the global object as its context.

Reading the source file you linked to, in this context (no pun intended) they're using `this` to obtain an *explicit* reference to the global object, without assuming that it's named either `window` (for a browser) or `global` (for node.js, etc).

(An IIFE is a common construct to create a new scope in which variables may be declared without polluting the global name space, and having the code within the block executed immediately).

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of doing so is that you can declare as many variables as you need inside the function, and they wouldn't pollute the global scope.

See also: [module pattern.](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)

Comment: I believe the OP is not asking about the IIFE, but the specific use of `FE.call(this)` instead of just `FE()`.

Comment: It allows you to tell the function who'll be bound as 'this' inside the function.